# Array remains empty after function ($http.post and for-loop)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax, asynchronous, nodes

The array 'relevantBoxes' does not contain the correct information afterwards. If appears to be empty.
I think this could be an asynchron problem, but I don't know how to change my code... I read a few pages today about asynchron behavior of javascript but it didn't really fit my case.
I also found a post here with > 2k upvotes, but this one also didn't help me -.-

Can somebody fast restructure my code or tell me where the problem is?

Any help is appreciated!

Greetings

```js
var o = {
boxesSubbed:[],
acceptancethreshold,
relevantBoxes[]
};

var currentLastAw;

        o.updateRelevantBoxes = function() {
         //Reset Boxes on start
            o.relevantBoxes = [];
            $http.get('/members-matter/mm-boxes/'+auth.currentUserId()+'/subbed/get-boxes').success(function(boxes){
                angular.copy(boxes, o.boxesSubbed);

                $http.get('/members-matter/mm-user/'+auth.currentUserId()+'/get-acceptance-threshold').success(function(threshold){
                    o.acceptancethreshold = threshold;

                    for(var i=0; i< o.boxesSubbed.length; i++){
                        (function () {
                            var currentBox = o.boxesSubbed[i];
                            $http.post('/members-matter/mm-boxes/get-last-answered', currentBox).success(function (lastaw){
                                currentLastAw = lastaw;
                                var data = {
                                    frequency:currentBox.frequency,
                                    lastanswered:currentLastAw
                                };
                                $http.post('/members-matter/mm-boxes/get-urgency', data).success(function (urgency){
                                    if(urgency > o.acceptancethreshold){
                                        o.relevantBoxes.push(currentBox);
                                    }
                                });
                            });
                        })();
                    }
                });
            });
        };
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'afterwards'?  When do you run updateRelevantBoxes?  Are you trying to read relevantBoxes right away because it will not be populated until the whole series of async call chains complete.  Have you looked into promises?

Comment: yes I did. I know how to use promises in general, but with this multiple http requests I don't know how to realize it.

Comment: Could you explain with your words what you are trying to do in your code ? Did you try to put some console.log() in the different steps of your code to see what's happening step by step ?